# Strange behavior with size limitation in Enterprise cache block

Tags: c#-4.0, enterprise-library

I am using entlib 5.0.1. I have created a cache using code configuration

```
IContainerConfigurator configurator = 
    new UnityContainerConfigurator(_unityContainer);
configurator.ConfigureCache(item.PartitionName, item.MaxItemNumber);
CacheBlockImp block = new CacheBlockImp(
    _unityContainer.Resolve<ICacheManager>(item.PartitionName), 
    item.PartitionType);
```

I saw a strange behavior with the size limit, I have configured the cache to hold 15 items, I am adding in a loop 18 items, I would suspect afer the addition to have only 15 items, but I get 8, when I have added a refresh action - to be notify when 1 item was evacuated, I really see that 7 of them were evacuated, all the items have the same priority.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        IContainerConfigurator configurator = new UnityContainerConfigurator(unityContainer);

        configurator.ConfigureCache("Test", 10);

        var cache = unityContainer.Resolve<ICacheManager>("Test");

        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
        {
            var dummy = new Dummy()
            {
                ID = i,
                Data = "hello " + i.ToString()
            };

            cache.Add(i.ToString(), dummy, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null, null);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        int count = cache.CachedItems().Count;
    }

    public class Dummy
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }


}


public static class CacheBlockExtension
{
    public static void ConfigureCache(this IContainerConfigurator configurator, string configKey,
        int maxNumOfItems)
    {
        ConfigurationSourceBuilder builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

        DictionaryConfigurationSource configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();

        // simple inmemory cache configuration
        builder.ConfigureCaching().ForCacheManagerNamed(configKey).WithOptions
            .StartScavengingAfterItemCount(maxNumOfItems)
            .StoreInMemory();
        builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);

        EnterpriseLibraryContainer.ConfigureContainer(configurator, configSource);
    }

    public static List<object> CachedItems(this ICacheManager cachemanger)
    {
        Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Cache cache =
            (Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Cache)cachemanger.GetType().GetField("realCache", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
           System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(cachemanger);

        List<object> tmpret = new List<object>();

        foreach (DictionaryEntry Item in cache.CurrentCacheState)
        {
            Object key = Item.Key;
            CacheItem cacheItem = (CacheItem)Item.Value;
            tmpret.Add(cacheItem.Value);
        }

        return tmpret;
    }
```

Comment: It's possible that Enterprise Library keeps the cache only half full for some reason. Have you considered using the caching capability built into .NET framework (in the System.Runtime.Caching assembly) instead? The Caching Application Block has been removed from Enterprise Library 6, due to this capability being part of the framework now.

Comment: i thought using it but it dont have all the features that the cache block has, it will be interesting to chack this half full issue

Comment: It looks like you are using some custom classes with your own extension methods.  Maybe if you posted a simpler code sample that can compile along with the configuration it would help.

Comment: added code in the post